# A shortcode to display the name of a category in a post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, shortcode

What I'm trying to do is find a way to display the name of a post category in WordPress, preperably as a shortcode. For example:

**[category-name]** Blah, blah, blah

on the post would be become

**Blog:** Blah, blah, blah

Is this at all possible? And what would be required to set it up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to display some category with a shortcode? See this one for an example

```
    add_shortcode('catlist', function($atts, $content) {
    $atts += array('category' => 1);
    $posts = get_posts("category={$atts['category']}");

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        echo $post->post_name . '<br />';
    }
});

echo do_shortcode('[catlist category=5]');
```

Comment: I'm trying to pull in the name of the category via a shortcode. So when you create a new post category you give it a name, slug, ect... I'm wanting a shortode that can identify the category that the post is under, then display it as text.

So a post under the 'Blog' category would just put the word 'Blog' wherever I put the shortcode. (Which will mainly be the post title)